# Having problem to run Castro User's Guide

Tags: git

I'm new to git and Castro.
I was trying to build the code as how it was taught on https://amrex-astro.github.io/Castro/docs/getting_started.html

But the step: "Now type make" confused me because it is not a command in git.
I used vi to edit the file. Or is there any way to edit file in git?

I tried to type make in git bash and vi. None of them have the command.

When make command is accepted, it should return a new file with code inside. So, later I can run the file.

Comment: "it is not a command in git... is there any way to edit file in git?"—I think you're very confused about what Git is. It's a version control system, nothing more. Maybe you're talking about "Git Bash" in Windows? This is just a shell that comes with Git on Windows, along with a bunch of other unix tools, since they're not available there.

Comment: In any case, you need a "make" program. Am I correct that you're on Windows?

Comment: yes, i'm running on Windows. I was thinking the "make" command refers to some file in the folder.

Comment: Nope. `make` is a command that operates on `Makefile`s. There should be a _`Makefile`_ (or `makefile`, or `Makefile.in`, or something) in the repo, but `make` needs to be installed separately, like Git itself. It looks like you'll also need compilers for Fortran and C++ to build this (GCC versions look like they'll work), and Python (unfortunately, it looks like it might only be compatible with version 2) to run it. This is a nontrivial program to build, and much of that process appears to be undocumented. Good luck!